# Looking for radial popup menu component for Delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface, menu, components, vcl

Radial menus have started appearing in several places.  I'm curious whether anyone has seen or is working on a radial menu component for Delphi?  We have a concept of what we'd like, shown in the animated gif at http://jmrsoftware.delaneyjoi.com/wheel.gif.  (It takes about 10 seconds for the menu animation to start.)

[alt text http://jmrsoftware.delaneyjoi.com/wheel.gif](http://jmrsoftware.delaneyjoi.com/wheel.gif)

Does anyone know of a component for Delphi that has similar functionality?

Thanks

Comment: If this control can really make toast, as the demo shows, I will be really impressed.

Comment: It seems like the sort of thing that someone somewhere holds a patent on and is just waiting for someone to take to court over.  I seem to recall very, very early releases of MacOS X (as in "Rhapsody" days) using something like this - or maybe that was just the rumormill, I don't quite recall.  I've not seen anything pre-built for Delphi that does it, in any event.

Comment: 1) This interface is currently used in the dolphin browser (not the HD variation) available on android phones
![alt text][1]

2) It is also used, in a more complex manner in this CAD program shown here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX2-8Dz0Cfw

3) being (or was) developed as an OS UI by a company called Emblaze Mobile, shown here http://www.engadget.com/2009/11/24/emblazes-first-else-unveiled-in-london-promises-to-be-a-game-c/

  [1]: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_bbZoRtK3YH8/S16BktaepBI/AAAAAAAAA68/duGrFIi_BnI/s320/Top+Android+App+Dolphin+Browser+Long+Press+Page+Options.png

Answer (score 1):

Radial or "pie" menus are underrated but are praised in HCI circles for being easy to use in a precise fashion. People find it easier to remember the path to an item on a radial menu that on a traditional linear-style menu, where the cursor needs to stay within a precise area to prevent a whole cascade of submenus from disappearing.

I've not seen a Delphi component that does it, but having coded them before in Delphi I'd recommend a package like Graphics32, perhaps deriving your pie menu from a paint box or image control that covers the entire form with a transparent overlay, and then renders/animates pie segments on top of that.